# Is it bad idea to use Dependency Injection objects in unit tests?

Tags: testing, dependency-injection, nunit

I am not sure if what i am doing is actually the "correct" way of doing unit tests with DI. Right now i ask my ViewModelLocator to actually create all the instances i need, and just get the instance i need to test, which makes it very simple to test a single instance because lets asume that Receipt needs a Reseller object to be created, reseller needs a User object to be created, user need some other object to be created, which creates a chain of objects to create just to test one single instance.

With di usally interfaces will get mocked and parsed to the object which you would like to create, but how about simple Entities/ViewModels?

Whats the best practice to do unit testing with DI involved?

```
 public class JournalTest
{
    private ReceiptViewModel receipt;
    private ViewModelLocator locator;
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        locator = new ViewModelLocator();

        receipt = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ReceiptViewModel>();
    }
    [TearDown]



    [Test]
    public void CheckAndCreateNewJournal_Should_Always_Create_New_Journal()
    {
        receipt.Sale.Journal = null;
        receipt.Sale.CheckAndCreateNewJournal();
        Assert.NotNull(receipt.Sale.Journal);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am curious, why does your business logic allow to set the `Journal` to `null` and have a 'initializer method' `CheckAndCreateNewJournal()`? Either your journal is mandatory and you initialize an empty journal in your Sale constructor (preferably into a readonly backing field) and guarantee it's invariant or you create and return one when the Journal property getter is called for the first time, if the backing field is `null`, but then you can't guarantee that class invariants. Having initializers is a code smell and hint of bad API design

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you aren't using Dependency Injection in your code. What you have there is called Service Locator (Service Locators create a tight coupling to the IoC/Service Locator and makes it hard to test).

And yes, it's bad (both Service Locator and Dependency Injection), because it means: You are not doing a UnitTest, you are doing an integration Test.

In your case the `ReceiptViewModel` will not be tested alone, but your test also tests the dependencies of `ReceiptViewModel` (i.e. Repository, Services injected etc.). This is called an integration test.

A UnitTest has to test only the class in question and **no dependencies**. You can achieve this either by stubs (dummy implementation of your dependencies, assuming you have used interfaces as dependencies) or using mocks (with a Mock framework like Moq).

Which is easier/better as you don't have to implement the whole class, but just have to setup mocks for the methods you know that will be required for your test case.

As an additional note, entities you'll got to create yourself. Depending on your UnitTest framework, there may be data driven tests (via Attributes on the test method) or you just create them in code, or if you have models/entities used in many classes, create a helper method for it.

View Models shouldn't be injected into constructor (at least avoided), as it couples them tightly

Comment: how do you want to use stubs/mocks without injecting them? Dependency injection is a perfect match for unit testing.

Comment: You create a mock and pass the mock in the constructor. It's still injecting, but not dependency injecting (where the container injects concrete types), just manual injection as in IoC

Comment: well, for me it's still dependency injection, but just manual

Answer (score 1):

Units tests should run quickly and should be deterministic. That means you have to mock/stub everything that brokes these two rules.

The best way to mock/stub dependancies is to inject them. In the production, classes are assembled by DI framework, but in unit tests you should assemble them manually and inject mocks where needed.

There is also a classic unit test approach where you stub/mock every dependency of your class, but it's useless since you don't gain anything by that. 
Martin Fowler wrote great article about that: [link](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html)
You should also read *Growing Object-oriented software: Guided by tests*. Ton of useful knowledge.